# Different structure when I copy text from PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, pdf-reader

When I copy and paste text from PDF, it shows different than it appears in the original.

For example:

In the original is "Hi my name is Victor and I am 23 years old".

When I copy and paste the text: "Hi and I am 23 my name is Victor"

How I can fix this problem? I am using Adobe Reader XI and a normal notepad or Microsoft Word when I paste the text. This is the first step because and I am trying to implement an app in c# and I should extract all text from many pdf documents, every time I extract the information with Itextsharp Library is the same thing, everything is a mess.

Thank you!

Comment: How was the PDF created?

Comment: Unknown, These PDF documents are hosted in certain page in internet.

Comment: I would also like to know the details of this. I'm writing my resume, and I think that when the PDF is copy and pasted, that's how it will end up looking like in some company's software when viewed by the hiring manager or automated systems of the ATS (Application Tracking System) type.

Comment: Apparently the program that you use to do the copying has a role in determining the order. Ie if I copy a document in MacOS's Pages app, I get a different result than copying in Adobe Acrobat.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to apply some sort of logic to your extraction process in C#.

PDF documents are not designed to be a useful method of storing text to then be used in other software or input in another format. PDF, by design, is a representation of a printed page, and consists of sets of instructions such as `Text of font A, size B at co-ordinate X,Y`. It doesn't use the same methods as, for example, Microsoft Word or HTML, where you format your document into grouped paragraphs or lines.

Effectively when you copy and paste out of the PDF software, it will interpret these instructions into something that vaguely mocks up our ideas of paragraph structures and will try and select them in the way you'd expect. However, as you've seen, this isn't always perfect and can easily go wrong.

I'm afraid the answer to your question is that this *problem* isn't so much a problem with your example, but a problem with using the PDF format for what you're trying to achieve. It's not designed for text parsing, although it can certainly be done, and iTextSharp will certainly have tools for you to achieve that, but you may have to 'simulate' line-by-line reading to do so.

Of course, you will find some PDF's that will appear to have been created perfectly and won't have a problem with copy and pasting from it. Remember though, this is more a case of the software *creating* the PDF using a predictable strategy to do so, and the software *reading* the PDF using a predictable strategy to get it back, rather than there being a perfect method of doing this.